# Wrap AES key with RSA public key - CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP

Tags: java, rsa, pkcs#11, hardware-security-module, oaep

I am using iaik pkcs11 java trying to wrap an AES key with RSA public key.

Can someone please help me what is the issue with above params/code?

I am trying to wrap an AES key with RSA public key. Getting issue as Mechanism invalid

```
    Mechanism mechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP);
    RSAPkcsOaepParameters rsaPkcsOaepParameters =
            new RSAPkcsOaepParameters(
                    Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_SHA256),
                    RSAPkcsParameters.MessageGenerationFunctionType.SHA256,
                    RSAPkcsOaepParameters.SourceType.EMPTY,
                    null);
    mechanism.setParameters(rsaPkcsOaepParameters);

    session.wrapKey(mechanism, wrappingKey, keyToWrap);
```

wrappingKey is an RSA public key handle and keyToWrap is an AES key

```
iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_MECHANISM_PARAM_INVALID
    at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation.C_WrapKey(Native Method) ~[iaik-pkcs11-wrapper-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Session.wrapKey(Session.java:1433) ~[iaik-pkcs11-wrapper-1.6.4.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you should use `RSAPkcsOaepParameters.SourceType.DATA_SPECIFIED` (`CKZ_DATA_SPECIFIED` as specified in [PKCS#11](https://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v3.0/cs01/pkcs11-curr-v3.0-cs01.html#_Toc228894636)):

```
public static Mechanism getRsaOaepSha256Mechanism() {
    Mechanism mechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP);
    RSAPkcsOaepParameters rsaPkcsOaepParameters =
            new RSAPkcsOaepParameters(
                    Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_SHA256),
                    RSAPkcsParameters.MessageGenerationFunctionType.SHA256,
                    RSAPkcsOaepParameters.SourceType.DATA_SPECIFIED,
                    null);
    mechanism.setParameters(rsaPkcsOaepParameters);
    return mechanism;
}
```

Good luck with your project!